# jQuery Validation for Arabic Digit Only

Tags: jquery

Using regex for validating `arabic digit only` using regex code `/^[\u0660-\u0669]{10}$/` it's not validating it work well with arabic digit but it also allowed arabic characters.I need to restrict it on for arabic digit.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ArabicInt", function(value, element) {         

    var arNumbers = value.replace(/\s+/g, '');        
    reg_arNumbers = /^[\u0660-\u0669]{10}$/;    
    if (reg_arNumbers.test(arNumbers)){
        return true;    
    }        
    else{           
            return false;                        
    }           
}, "Not an arabic number");
```

Comment: I fixed it reg_arNumbers = /^[\u0660-\u0669]*$/; this regex work for Arabic number and  reg_arNumbers = /^[\u0660-\u0669]{10}$/;  this allow arabic digit and characters.

Comment: `/^[\u0660-\u0669]{10}$/` is supposed to allow exactly 10 arabic digits, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

It work for Arabic Digits and Arabic Characters

```
 reg_arNumbers = /^[\u0660-\u0669]{10}$/;
```

For Allowing only Arabic Digits

```
 reg_arNumbers = /^[\u0660-\u0669]*$/;
```